# how configure Google analytics for same page with multiple ids?

Tags: google-analytics

Hi i need to configure GA for page with multiple ids(or params). The values are changing dynamically.

For example

```
www.example.com/123ewr
www.example.com/ewrewr
```

These pages were landing same page with different contents.how to get separate analytics for that?

Comment: Not quite clear what you want (subdirs will be tracked by default) - do you need a different tracker per subdirectory ?

Comment: yes i need seperate statistics for each of those examples

Comment: create two profiles and add filters

Comment: @DalmTo and what if there is more than these strings or they are random?

Comment: Implement GA via tag manager, do a lookup table that sets the tracking id according to directory (or build your own lookup table in javascript). You have to know the tracking id for each tracker in advance, so "random" will not work in any case.